# Mainting UIButton on UINavigationBar throughout app?

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, title

I'm try to set up a navigation-based app with a UIButton (to provide 'about' information) as the title on the navigation bar. I can easily establish the button as the title but can't figure out where I should do it so it is permanent (and the navigation-bar doesn't slide each time a new viewController is called). Here's my current code:

```
AppDelegate.h

    @class ViewController;
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

@end

AppDelegate.m

    #import "AppDelegate.h"
    #import "ViewController.h"
    @implementation AppDelegate

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc]    initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
        } else {
            self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];
        }
        UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
        self.window.rootViewController = navController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        return YES;
    }

ViewController.m

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 4, 120, 36);
        [button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo_1.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(about) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        self.navigationItem.titleView = button;
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }
```

For clarification, the code from 'viewDidLoad' works fine - I just want to have it set up at start and last forever (I have no problem using singleton's for the actual method - I just don't want it to be reloaded).

I've been digging through the site and tinkering for a couple hours and can't seem to get this working; thanks ahead of time for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `UIViewController` pushed onto the `UINavigationController` stack has it's own `UINavigationBar` so there is no way to have a global button. What you can to is create a common base class for each of the `ViewControllers` the setup the button in the base class `viewDidLoad`.

I created a sample App to demonstrate this approach.

https://github.com/GayleDDS/SameButtonOnAllNavBars

[image]

Comment: could you please elaborate on how that is accomplished? it sounds like it may not be possible for the naviBar to not slide, but I can recount several applications that do so. I presume they use ViewControllers and aren't hosting each view out of one/minimal classes.

Comment: @Ryan I created a sample app on GitHub to demo.

Comment: Thanks Gayle - I really appreciate your help. I've had no trouble doing this, and I actually use plenty of Singleton's already in my app so - unless I'm missing something monumental - all I can do is call the method from each class to get the navigation items I want. But I can't permanently/statically have my navigation bar sit up top? Am I missing something in your code? Why is there a difference between the titleView and the rightItem in that the title slides off while the rightItem can stay? Thanks again.

Comment: Hi @Ryan the sliding behavior is because of the way Apple had designed the `UINavigationController` class. The title moves with the content to help the user understand that content is being pushed on and off the stack. As long as the buttons are assigned in viewDidLoad or 'viewWillAppear' (not 'viewDidAppear`) and they are the same it looks static (OpenGL is smart and fast so no flickering).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Gayle. You've been a big help!